# Prevent silence of the phone

Tags: java, android, audio

I am working on a program that plays long audio files. How can I keep the phone screen on as long as there is an audio file being played?

Answer (score 0):

put this in you mainactivity.java file

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

then this in your layout file in which layout you want to wake up

```
android:keepScreenOn="true">
```